# Updating a gem that is only a dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

How do you update a gem that is a dependency but not in my Gemfile?  For example, I am receiving a `bundler-audit` warning that I need to use `eventmachine 1.0.4`, but it is not in my Gemfile. However it is in my Gemfile lock at version 1.0.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach was to put the following into my Gemfile

```
gem 'eventmachine', '~> 1.0.4', require: false
```

then I did `bundle update eventmachine`.  When doing this, I chose the earliest release is needed.

This fixed the `bundler-audit` warning and all my tests passed. The require false should mean that `eventmachine` should only be called when necessary.

Comment: When the gem is dependency to another gem. It is not recommended to upgrade directly. Instead you have to update the parent gem, so that all it's dependencies will be updated.

Comment: You are right, and presumably you look at the ```Gemfile.lock``` to find the parent gem.  Why not do it as an answer and I will make it the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

When the gem is dependency to another gem. It is not recommended to upgrade directly. Instead you have to update the parent gem, so that all it's dependencies will be updated.